# Download image from Desktop application adobe air

Tags: image, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4

Switched flex browser to flex desktop application. Was using navigateToURL to download images from the browser but clicking the button in the desktop app, its opening the browser and I dont want that to happen. Can I still use navigateToURL or do I need something else?

Code right now:

```
fileRef = new FileRefrence();
url.url = dest;
url.method = "GET";
url.data = variables;
url.contentType = "multipart/form-data";
fileRef.download(url, variables.filename);
```

Comment: **(1)** Use `Loader` to display the image inside your app or else **(2)** Use `fileReference` or `FileStream` to save as file to storage. Tutorials available on first page of Google for whichever you need.

Comment: The **navigateToURL(...)** method is supposed to pass the request to the current browser window (or open a new one if there is none). You can download and save files without browser via **FileReference.download(...)** method:
 https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download()

Comment: Can someone show me an example of how maybe it can be done @Organis

Comment: The link in my previous comment also provides an example.

Comment: I tried doing it, its opening the file explorer but not saving the file when clicking Save @Organis

Comment: @Organis Got it to save but the zip folder is empty, its not saving the image into the zip, any ideas?

Comment: updated the code of how it looks right now

Comment: 1. Are you sure that **GET** and **multipart/form-data** are compatible options? I think they are mutually exclusive. 2. I'd enable some logging from the server side to understand if the request was processed correctly and non-empty answer was dispatched.

Comment: @Karam It should be `fileRef.download( new URLRequest( "yourFilePath" ), "saveName");` ... where `yourFilePath` is a String that looks like `https://www...` etc and also set a String of your preferred save name of the file.